# Default template parameter cannot be used inside another template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction

I have a class template with a default value for the template parameter:

```cpp
template<typename T = int>
class DefaultType : private std::array<T, 5> { };
```

and since c++17 this can be instantiated like a normal class

```cpp
DefaultType obj; // equivalent to `DefaultType<>`
```

The same thing cannot be done if I use this type as an argument for another template:

```cpp
// error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ...
class Foo : public std::vector<DefaultType> { };
```

yet, the above snippet *does* compile with `DefaultType<>`.
[(godbolt)](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:54,endLineNumber:14,positionColumn:54,positionLineNumber:14,selectionStartColumn:54,selectionStartLineNumber:14,startColumn:54,startLineNumber:14),source:%27%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%23include+%3Carray%3E%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+T+%3D+int%3E%0Aclass+DefaultType+:+private+std::array%3CT,+5%3E+%7B+%7D%3B%0A%0Aclass+TestType+:+public+std::vector%3CDefaultType%3E+%7B+%7D%3B%0A%0A%0A%0Atemplate%3Cstd::size_t+N+%3D+5%3E%0Aclass+DefaultNonType+:+private+std::array%3Cint,+N%3E+%7B+%7D%3B%0A%0Aclass+TestNonType+:+public+std::vector%3CDefaultNonType%3E+%7B+%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++DefaultType+t%3B%0A++++DefaultNonType+nt%3B%0A++++%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50.496083550913845,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%271%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B17%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:63.311058686183955,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:49.50391644908617,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

what's the reason for that? would a deduction guide help? and what about NTTPs?

Comment: [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) only applies in some contexts... `Foo`'s usage doesn't use one of those.

Comment: Is `DefaultType<>` really less convenient here? The empty brackets are only two characters more.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica it's not really invonvenient, but seems like inconsistent behavior of the language. I was wondering if I'm missing something.

Comment: It'd be more inconsistent if the language allowed  it IMO. *All* arguments being optional is very niche. The majority of templates don't do that. The implementation will need to *special-case* this behavior rather than parsing in uniform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
DefaultType obj;
```

uses [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) (class template argument deduction) which is available since C++17 and only in certain contexts:

> - any declaration that specifies initialization of a variable and variable template
> - new-expressions
> - function-style cast expressions
> - the type of a non-type template parameter:

To instantiate `DefaultType` with the default argument in other contexts you still need to write `DefaultType<>`.

I suppose the reason to have CTAD only in certain contexts is that those are the contexts where you always want an instantiation, but never the template.